# How to implement the new Google Play Services (Analytics)?

Tags: java, android, google-analytics

I don't know exactly how to implement the new GPS Analytics into my app. My problem is located at the 4th step being described [here](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v4/). I dont know how to use

```
Tracker t = ((AnalyticsSampleApp) getActivity().getApplication()).getTracker(
            TrackerName.APP_TRACKER);
```

correctly. More exactly what do I need to write for **AnalyticsSampleApp**.

My Apps package name is com.mnd.tsst

My global_tracker.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

300

```
<!-- Enable automatic Activity measurement -->
<bool name="ga_autoActivityTracking">true</bool>

<!-- The screen names that will appear in reports -->
<screenName name="com.google.android.gms.analytics.samples.mobileplayground.ScreenviewFragment">
    TimetableApp TimeTableView
</screenName>
<!--  The following value should be replaced with correct property id. -->
<string name="ga_trackingId">UA-xxxxxx-5</string>
```

I entered a correct property ID, just removed it to show it here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to create a new class that extends `Application` class with any name you want (say, `MyApp`)

In this class you have to add the methods and fields as suggested in the guide to be added to `Application` class.

```
public class MyApp extends Application {
    public enum TrackerName {
        APP_TRACKER,
        GLOBAL_TRACKER,
        E_COMMERCE_TRACKER,
    }

    HashMap<TrackerName, Tracker> mTrackers = new HashMap<TrackerName, Tracker>();

    synchronized Tracker getTracker(TrackerName trackerId) {

        if (!mTrackers.containsKey(trackerId)) {

            GoogleAnalytics analytics = GoogleAnalytics.getInstance(this);
            Tracker t = (trackerId == TrackerName.APP_TRACKER) ? analytics.newTracker(PROPERTY_ID)
                    : (trackerId == TrackerName.GLOBAL_TRACKER) ? analytics.newTracker(R.xml.global_tracker)
                    : analytics.newTracker(R.xml.ecommerce_tracker);
            mTrackers.put(trackerId, t);
        }
        return mTrackers.get(trackerId);
    }
}
```

Also, add the following in the `application` tag of your manifest:

```
android:name=".MyApp"
```

where `MyApp` is the name you have given to your `Application` class.

In the global_tracker.xml file, I have yet understand the purpose of `screenName`, but however, for the time being, you should at least modify the sample package address to package name of your own Activities.

Now, let's say to send a screen view to Analytics, you would simply type anywhere inside any activity (maybe in onCreate or onResume):

```
Tracker t = ((MyApp) getApplication()).getTracker(
                        TrackerName.APP_TRACKER);       // Get tracker.
t.setScreenName(ACTIVITY_NAME);     // Pass a String representing the screen name.
t.send(new HitBuilders.AppViewBuilder().build());       // Send a screen view.
```

Similarly, to send an event (maybe from onClick of some button)

```
Tracker t = ((MyApp) getActivity().getApplication()).getTracker(
                    TrackerName.APP_TRACKER);
t.send(new HitBuilders.EventBuilder()
 .setCategory(categoryString)
 .setAction(actionString)
 .setLabel(labelString)
 .build());
```

This should give you a head-start.

Comment: I'm a complete newb. On my website, I just paste a Javascript. Where does the class "go"?

Comment: @Andy You should use this in a Android application. Not a website

Comment: Can you please tell me what is PROPERTY_ID in this case, is it the property number associated with the account??

Comment: @user2700252 It is the ID generated by Google Analytics whenever you create a new app/website (commonly called as a Property) on their website, and is associated with that Property. It is usually of the format UA-xxxxxxxx-y. Log in to your Analytics account to find the relevant PROPERTY_ID on the dashboard itself.

Comment: is R.xml.ecommerce_tracker any different than R.xml.global_tracker? If so, how?

Comment: @ViksaaSkool For every different type of tracker you want to have, you will need separate xml file as well as define it as a type in the enum. E.g. e-commerce tracker, game progress tracker, app engagement tracker etc. A main app level tracker, or a super global tracker common to all your apps to measure some stuff can be there.